# How do I execute PHP in Wordpress 3.2.1 pages, posts, widgets, etc?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been using the Exec-PHP plugin, but it's no longer working with the latest update to WP.

Anyone else run into this problem and find a solution?

Comment: Have you looked at your error logs? Are you seeing any error output? What have you tried to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin which I have run successfully on a WP 3.2.1 site.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to install a plugin, have a look at this idea of LxC, it worked for me with WP 3.5.1. ->[PHP in WP Post without plugin](http://lxcblog.com/2011/11/05/run-execute-include-php-code-wordpress-posts-no-plugin/)

You basically add a function to your theme which will execute the embedded php code. This function you then call before the post's text gets filtered by WP, simple and effective :)